# How to detect keypresses on a BasicPage in c# win8 Metro

Tags: windows, c#-4.0, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I want to **catch the keypresses regardless of the focus on any control.**
what event to fire and where. 
I've tried to override **OnKeyDown and OnKeyUp** but that doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a tapped event for the UIElements

You can read more here about events
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465387.aspx

Comment: This answer is almost a link-only answer.  If the link were to break in the future, your answer would not have much value.  I suggest you add some more information to your answer so it can stand on its own without the link.